# Depth first search using java

Tags: java, tree, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

I want to implement DFS (Depth first search)  and BFS using java.

Does java have a built in tree data structure that I can use readly? Or any other thing that I can use?

Comment: t@adamski. thanks man. i dint know that my votinting help someone. frm now i will

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at http://www.jgrapht.org/ where a free java graph library is provided. Using this library you can create all kind of graphs, and since tree's is just a subset of graphs you can also create tree's with this library. A DFS (or BFS) is easy to implement using this library, or you can use the algorithms provided by the library. However, implementing a DFS (or BFS) is a good exercise.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [DefaultMutableTreeNode](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html) to build your data structure.  It contains methods `breadthFirstEnumeration()` and `depthFirstEnumeration()` and allows you to attach data to each node by calilng `setUserObject(Object)`.  Despite part of the `javax.swing.tree` package this is "model" code and so doesn't have any direct UI code dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want duplicates in your structure, then TreeSet is a decent enough starting point. You get DFS for free (iterator()), and you can make use of the NavigableSet interface to build BFS.

Comment: A couple of restrictions to bear in mind: TreeSet enforces that the underlying data is modelled as a binary tree and that it is comparable.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no built-in structure. Given the Java base libraries have everything, it is crazy there is no equivalent to [Data.Tree](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.6/html/libraries/base/Data-Tree.html)

The closest is java.util.TreeSet, which is designed to be a Set rather than a Tree (there's also the swing JTree, but it won't help you).

Comment: its pretty easy to crate a Tree data type - for a lib, its hard to make it general enough for all use cases, but all the needed parts are there in java already.